# Capture screen output stream

Tags: c#, .net, screen-recording

Is there a way to access the raw graphics card output stream and store it in a buffer, so that it can be compressed and saved? Using C# and .net, or any open source C# API's.

Comment: Not sure I correctly understand what you want. Are you trying to capture what is currently displayed on the screen or are you more interested in the graphic memory of your computer?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a stream class.   It is an electronic dump of the screen memory to the monitor.  I is serial, but not in any form that is usable by a program.  You need to capture the data in the screen buffer memory.